# Plotting several runs of the same function on one plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a function that gives me 3 outputs T, A and B

I am attempting to plot several runs of the function on the same plot. I am getting a new plot for each run. I have put the code below please see if you know a fix :)

```
# create the different runs
setT=[]
setA=[]
setB=[]
for i in range(5):
    smallNT,smallNA,smallNB = ABA(50,40,3,2)
    setT.append(smallNT)
    setA.append(smallNA)
    setB.append(smallNB)

#plot the runs
def plotr(feat1,feat2,feat3):
    time1=[]
    size1=[]
    size2=[]
    for i in range(0,100):
        time1.append(feat1[i])
        size1.append(feat2[i])
        size2.append(feat3[i])

    plt.plot(time1,size1, 'ro')
    plt.plot(time1,size2, 'bo')
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("size of population")
    plt.show()

#trying to plot them all together
for i in range(5):
    plotr(setT[i],setA[i],setB[i])
```

Comment: You are showing the plot with plt.show() every time plotr() is called. Move xlabel, ylabel, and show() to the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I randomly generate those sets of data `setT`, `setA`, and `setB`. Each  is a 5x20 array (5 runs and each run has 20 data points).

I would suggest you to create an `Axis` by using `plt.subplots` outside the loop. It will return both `Figure` and `Axis`. Then you pass the `Axis` variable into the function, so that we can reuse it multiple times.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

setT = np.random.rand(5, 20)
setA = np.random.rand(5, 20)
setB = np.random.rand(5, 20)

def plotr(ax, feat1,feat2,feat3):
    ax.plot(feat1, feat2, 'ro')
    ax.plot(feat1, feat3, 'bo')
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("size of population")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5):
    plotr(ax, setT[i],setA[i],setB[i])
plt.show()
```

If you want to plot only the first `N` data points, you don't need to create a new list and assign them to the list using another for loop like you did. You can just use list slicing like `feat1[:N]` or `feat[:100]`. Thus, inside the `plotr` function, you change those two lines to be:

```py
    ax.plot(feat1[:100], feat2[:100], 'ro')
    ax.plot(feat1[:100], feat3[:100], 'bo')
```